# (Homework) Proving exactness of the relative Mayer-Vietoris Sequence

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Given open sets $A,\,B \subset X$ for some space $X$ and $C \subset A \cup B$, we are supposed to show that there are long relative Mayer-Vietoris sequences

$$
\newcommand{H}[3]
{H_{#1}\left(#2,\,#3\right)}
\dots \rightarrow \H{k}{X}{A\cap B} \rightarrow \H{k}{X}{A} \oplus \H{k}{X}{B} \rightarrow \H{k}{X}{A \cup B} \rightarrow \H{k-1}{X}{A\cap B}\rightarrow \dots \\
$$
By using the LESes for the involved pairs, I can get long exact columns containing the sequence as a row inside a commutative diagram (the direct sum is simply the direct sum of the LESes). Connected by the inclusions. There also seemed an obvious way to construct the boundary homomorphism $\H{k}{X}{A \cup B} \rightarrow \H{k-1}{X}{A\cap B}$, but I can't really prove the claim. If I remember correctly, the chain property wasn't the problem, exactness was, though.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something crucial in my approach. Can someone help me gain an idea?